# cassandra Converts UUID to Year month date

Tags: cassandra

I have **uuid** (**caf69569-4ae2-4399-bf99-3243a1035206**) in **cassandra** and wanted to convert it in **date (Ymd) format**. Can i do that ?

Comment: if you use timeUUID as your datatype then you'll be able to extract the date info you need. the UUID datatype can't be converted to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can refer this, here it describes Converts UUID to date

[Converting TimeUUID Strings to Dates](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204226019-Converting-TimeUUID-Strings-to-Dates)

hope this will help